# Get position of UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cgrect

I have a button in a static UITableViewCell. What I want to do is place a UIView at the buttons location.

If I just get the buttons position, it will give me a position relative to the tableviews cell, not from the top of the tableViewController. What I want is get the buttons position from the top of the tableViewController.

> For example: If the button is 8px away from the top of the current
>   cell, but 57px away from the top of the viewController, I want to
>   place the UIView at 57px.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    CGRect rect = [myTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"%f, %f", rect.origin.y, rect.origin.x);

    self.infoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, 220, 110)];
}
```

The output of the nslog is 0.

I would also like to update the UIView's position whenever the iphone goes to landscape mode.

Comment: this is a custom cell?

Comment: do you have an instance of button?

Comment: button gets called from an array of buttons like so: UIButton *button = [self.allButtons objecAtIndex:1];

Comment: To your Y position add the result of multiplying the number of rows before the row with the button and the rows height. But I suspect there's a better way to do whatever you're trying to do. So tell us, what your real goal is?

Comment: `button.frame.origin.x` and `button.frame.origin.y` gives you buttons position

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If the button is 8px away from the top of the cell, but 57px away from the top of the viewController, I want to get 57px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGPoint originalPoint = button.frame.origin;
CALayer *layer = self;
CGPoint point = originalPoint;
while (layer.superlayer)
{
    point = [layer convertPoint:point toLayer:layer.superlayer];
    layer = layer.superlayer;
}

//When you reach this code, you should have the position in the rootView
```